# When defining class method, why there an equals sign in argument e.g. func(foo=3)

Tags: python, function, class, parameter-passing

I'm learning python, trying to figure out how does this code actually work:

```
def func(**args):
    class BindArgs(object):
       foo = args['foo']
       print 'foo is ', foo
       def __init__(self,args):
           print "hello i am here"
    return BindArgs(args) #return an instance of the class

f = func(foo=2)
```

Output:

`foo is  2
hello i am here`

But it's very confused that in the argument of a function `func(foo=2)` that takes equation mark in it. Could you please explain how the flow works?

Comment: The answer from the link is that: in my example, `args == 'foo'  ` and `args['foo'] == 2`. Quick question, if class `GindArgs(object)` could take type `**args` as argument, does that mean regular class could actually take "keyword (dictionary)" as argument too?

Comment: Yes, functions and therefore class constructions can get a dictionary as their arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an abstract:
You call the function `func` and pass a dictionary as the argument to it.
In the func function, you define a class named BindArgs, and then in the return statement, you first make an object (instance) from the BindArgs class and then return that instance.
Notice that the statement `foo = args['foo']` get the key value of `'foo'` from the `args` dictionary (that is `2` in your sample code).
the `init` also will be run as the constructor of the class when you are creating an object.